# On MacOS, error => "EBADF: bad file descriptor, close"

Tags: node.js, file-descriptor, tty

I am trying to pipe the stdout/stderr of a child process to a specific terminal/TTY.

Here is my code:

```
//start

    if ($fd !== undefined) {
      try {
        fs.closeSync($fd)
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
      }
    }


    $fd = fs.openSync(fd_stdout, 'a');

    child = cp.spawn(executable, execStringArray, { });

    child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

    const strm = fs.createWriteStream(projectWatcherOutputLogPath);
    child.stdout.pipe(strm);
    child.stderr.pipe(strm);



    if (tty.isatty($fd)) {
      console.error('fd with value => ', $fd, '*is* a tty!');
      const stdoutStrm = fs.createWriteStream(null, { fd: $fd });
      child.stdout.pipe(stdoutStrm);
    }
    else {
      console.error('fd with value => ', $fd, 'is not a tty');
    }

    if (tty.isatty($fd)) {
      console.error('fd with value => ', $fd, '*is* a tty!');
      const stderrStrm = fs.createWriteStream(null, { fd: $fd });
      child.stderr.pipe(stderrStrm);
    }


   else {
       console.error('fd with value => ', $fd, 'is not a tty');
    }

   child.on('close', function () {
      console.log(' => Suman server => project-watcher child process has fired "close" event.');
    });
//end
```

what happens is after this working once, I get an error:

```
EBADF: bad file descriptor, close
```

there is no further stack trace besides that, even if I use the node execArgv `'--trace-warnings'`.

**Perhaps I need to close the file after opening it?**

Comment: any solution for this?